# Updating data on the page while select box changes

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

I need to bring data from database when the page loads AND everytime I change the value of my dropdown list.

This is the function I'm using to bring the data:(I *had to* use Query Builder)

```
public function myFunction($param1, $param2)
   {
      return DB::select('
          SELECT field1, field2, field3
          FROM table1            
          WHERE field1 = '. $param1.' AND field2 = "' . $param2 . '"            
        ');
    }
```

This is how I'm bringing data when the page *loads*:

```
public function getList()
   {
     //here I get all the avaliable semesters to fill the select box
     $semesters = MyModel::distinct()->select('field2')->get()->toArray();
     return View::make('myView', compact('semestres'));
   }
```

#### My View:

```
<select name='semesters' id='semesters'>
   @foreach($semestres as $semester)                    
      <option value='{{ $semester["data"] }}'>{{ $semestre['data'] }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>



 @foreach($myModel->myFunction($myModel->param1, $semesters[0]['param2']) as $disc)
     <li> 
          {{ $disc->otherField }}
     </li>
 @endforeach
```

As you can see, at first I get the very first value of my `semesters`array to filter the data (because this semester value will be the selected one on my select box). Now when I change the select box value, I'd like to 're-filter' the data according to the new selected value. Don't know how to do it.

Comment: you have typing mistake in return View::make('myView', compact('semesters'));

Comment: You can write ajax for dropdown onchange event. refer http://laravel.io/forum/09-23-2014-loading-views-with-ajax

Comment: Have you tried with Ajax?